# Как сделать граф в C# из списка

Tags: c#

У меня есть список (список смежности):

("Первая точка","Вторая точка"),
("Вторая точка","Третья точка"),
("Третья точка","Первая точка") и т.д.

Как на его основе реализовать граф?

Comment: Реализовать граф - это что значит? Вывести на экран? Или задать граф? Также, вы представляете какой именно граф вы хотите получить? Просто рёбра, с направлением, с весами?

Comment: @AK, Я тут понял, что это называется: "список смежности", мне нужно чтобы метод возвращал граф. Граф мультиграф.

Comment: Что имеется ввиду под _возвращал граф_? В каком виде? Собственно данный список и так является графом.

Comment: Чтобы возвращался класс с графом который представляет собой: name-названия ребра, его состояние и список графов которые смежные с ним

Comment: что за состояние ребра? граф ориентированный?

Comment: @Grundy, ориентированный граф, Да я ошибсся извините

Comment: ты же сам написал: _name-названия ребра, **его состояние**_

Comment: @Grundy, Извините, я просто запутался. не ориентированный граф(на чушь выше исправил), а состояние, чтобы смотреть был ли ты в данной точке.

Answer (score 0):

В целом граф состоит из списка вершин и списка ребер:

```
class Graf
{
    List<Vertex> V;
    List<Edge> E;
    Graf()
    {
        V = new List<Vertex>();
        E = new List<Edge>();
    }
    Graf(List<Vertex> V1, List<Edge> E1)
    {
        V = V1;
        E = E1;
    }
}


class Vertex
{
    public int x, y;
    public Color color;
    public int Vertex_Stepen;
    public int Vertex_number;



    public Vertex(int x,int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        color = Color.White;
        Vertex_number = 0;
        Vertex_Stepen = 0;
    }

    public Vertex(int x, int y,Color c)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        color = c;
        Vertex_number = 0;
        Vertex_Stepen = 0;
    }
}

class Edge
{
    //номера вершин
    public int v0;
    public int v1;


   public Edge(int v0, int v1)
    {
        this.v0 = v0;
        this.v1 = v1;
    }
}

// код взят из моего старого проекта,который делался для себя, поэтому его можно (и наверное даже нужно)
// улучшить,но в целом все так выглядит
```

Ps color нужен для цвета вершин,можно и без него

Comment: Большое спасибо, за эти классы. Но мне бы просто алгоритм, как создать из списка ребер граф.

Comment: @chilo5432 тогда нужен точный формат входных данных и под них придётся писать парсер

Comment: @chilo5432 что вообще значит тогда создать граф?тут в коде понятный алгоритм уже есть,чуть-чуть подумать надо.Любой граф из ребер делается через список ребер путем создания каждого ребра и добавления ему списка смежных вершин

Comment: @chilo5432 могу дать ссыль на википедию https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84_(%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0) если уж на то пошло

Comment: @TEA, Под графом имел ввиду взять начальную точку и от него по ребрам строить граф. И вот это получившиеся чудо я думал должно возвращать.

Comment: @TEA, Я уже решил данную задачу. Еще не до конечной стадии. Но уже близко. Большое спасибо за помощь!